# What is the typical file size of an ASP.NET Temporary Files, folder?

Tags: asp.net, temporary-files

I know this is a bit like *how long is a piece of string* question, but I'm wondering how big some peoples ASP.NET Temporary Files folder, gets. I wish to move this folder to a RAM DISK so I'm trying to see how big this should be set, to.

eg. `<compilation tempDirectory=“R:\ASP.Net Temporary Folder\” debug=“false“>`

This is only for my DEVELOPMENT Machine (to help speed up compiling -> temp crap goes to ram instead of the Disk).

Is 256MB big enough? What about file uploading? where do those files (temporarily) go?

Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

From my experience on my web server and on many sites **256 MB is big enough for one site.**

**The 10Mg files (only aspx and cs) product about 20-40Mg files on temporary (plus your files on bin directory).**

I check my server that runs many asp.net v4 and v3.5 sites and I have temporary dirs up to 40Mg on the very huge projects. Most of the sites use 1-4Gb.

The uploading files not go to this temporary file, but they go where you have set to go on upload.

Hope this help you.